# How do I use CSS transformations to slide a div on screen?

Tags: css, ipad, safari, html, webkit

My web page has two divs on it, A and B. Div A is visible, Div B is hidden.

When the user clicks a link in div A, I want to "slide" div A off screen (leaving via the left edge), and slide div B on screen (entering via the right edge).

I've found that jquery animations are very slow on the ipad, so I want to use the webkit CSS animations instead, which I believe are rendered in hardware. How do I do this?

Comment: Just to be persnickety, it’s CSS *transitions* or CSS animations. CSS transforms are when you change an object’s shape.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite transform: translate(x, y) is just changing position, not shape. Right?

Comment: @MdaG: ah yes, very true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is an example showing how to do this with webkit animations.  You might also read this article for more background: http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/

The rounded corners are just to show that the page is moving off screen, not just changing width.

The main idea is to animate the left CSS property and use a container div to do clipping.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-in; 
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-in; 
}

#left.animate {
  left: -50px;
}

#right.animate {
  left: 0px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script>

function animate() {
  document.getElementById('left').className = 'animate';
  document.getElementById('right').className = 'animate';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'><div id='left'></div><div id='right'></div></div>
<input type='button' onclick='animate();' value='Animate!'></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your exemple here with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/bB5sK/ "jsfiddle ").

Comment: To have the #left div "slide" off, you need to give it "left: 0px;" initially: http://jsfiddle.net/7QWGj/